# Iterate over list to get value by its name

Tags: r, list, iteration, key-value, sapply

This works. But are there more efficient/simpler ways to get `output`?

```
test_list <- list(list("name"="A","property"=1),
              list("name"="B","property"=2),
              list("name"="C","property"=3))

myFunction <- function(arg1=NULL, arg2=NULL){
  arg1[[arg2]]
}

# works
output <- sapply(test_list, myFunction, "property")

# returns NULL 
# output <- sapply(test_list, `$`, "property")
```

Comment: YOu can use `sapply(test_list, function(x) x$property)`

Comment: `sapply(test_list, '[[', "property")` or `sapply(test_list, getElement, name="property")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the anonymous function call to do the extraction

```
sapply(test_list, function(x) x$property)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: I missed out on the x argument. Thanks.

Comment: Generally one should avoid using "$" inside functions, so a better answer would use: `function(x) x[['property']]`