# Why `$` failed to subset list elements when passed to sapply/lapply as FUN argument while `[[` works?

Tags: r, subset, lapply

This post is based on this question:([Iterate over list to get value by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510682/iterate-over-list-to-get-value-by-its-name))

I'll reproduce it here:

```
test_list <- list(list("name"="A","property"=1),
              list("name"="B","property"=2),
              list("name"="C","property"=3))
```

The original OP found:

```
sapply(test_list, `$`, "property")
```

only return `NULL` values. It gives correct results if when use `[[` instead as commented by jogo:

```
> sapply(test_list, `$`, "property")
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

> sapply(test_list, `[[`, "property")
[1] 1 2 3
```

This also does not work:

```
> sapply(test_list, function(x, y) `$`(x, y), y = "property")
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

However, both `$` and `[[` works on a single element of `test_list`:

```
> `$`(test_list[[1]], 'property')
[1] 1
> `[[`(test_list[[1]], 'property')
[1] 1
```

I wonder why `$` and `[[` behave differently when used as `FUN=` argument for lapply/sapply.

Comment: This one works: `sapply(test_list, function(x) `$`(x, "property"))`. There are backquotes around the dollar sign.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for the hint. It seems `$(x, y)` is doing something like `x$"y"` without even evaluating `y`. There isnot any `"y"` element so that we only get `NULL`. See MrFlick's answer to the linked question for more details.

Comment: Answered e.g. here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560090/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-r-function)  or here [link2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-accessors-explained/). The two subsetting operators are not equal in their functionality.

Comment: @RadimHladik, very helpful. The link2 well-summarized the differences between `$`and `[[`.